# How to read key/value in xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml-parsing, console-application

I am trying to build a console project which reads an ASP.NET project's web.config file. I need to read a value from the config. I am putting what I want to read from the web.config file.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="LogoFrmNumber" value="001"/>
  <add key="LogoFrmPeriod" value="01"/>
</appSettings>
```

I want to read LogoFrmNumber's value like I read regular xml file. How can I read that value.

here is my code to read web.config but I am stuck.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "c://web.config" );

var values = doc.Descendants( "AppSettings" );

foreach ( var value in values )
{
     Console.WriteLine( value.Value );
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: If your question is specifically about the configuration of tha app, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c2kcht0(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionary is your best choice to keep the data including the method to read attributes

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "c://web.config" );
       var elements = doc.Descendants( "AppSettings" );
        Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
            {
               string key = elements[i].Attributes["key"].Value.ToString();
               string value = elements[i].Attributes["value"].Value.ToString();
               keyValues.Add(key,value);
            }
```

Comment: what declaration of elements ? if you mean the dictionary - yes it has to be <string, string> my mistake editing

Answer (score 4):

Below snippet looks most elegent and simple way to do your needs. Try out

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"c:\web.config";
Configuration configuration=ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = configuration.AppSettings.Settings;
foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement item in settings)
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key : {0}  Value : {1}", item.Key, item.Value ));
}
```

Please mark the answer if it is useful