# C# Trouble looping through elements in XML stream

Tags: c#, xml, stream

I have a URL that outputs XML when accessed and I want to read that XML as a stream (I think) and loop over the elements to do something with the data, but I'm getting strange results.

My code so far:

```
private void getFaxFinderLogs()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://faxfinder/ffws/v1/inbound_log");
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ffusername_tb.Text, ffpassword_tb.Text);

    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

        foreach (var el in xdoc.Elements())
        {
            debugTextBox1.Text = string.Format("Key={0},value={1}", el.Name, el.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

And the XML from the URL above produces this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<response>
    <message>Success</message> 
    <inbound_fax_entry>
        <filename>fax_inbound_20170313_133831_recv0943.pdf</filename> 
        <status>complete</status> 
        <complete_time>2017-03-13T17:38:31</complete_time> 
        <remote_id>5551239999</remote_id> 
        <pages>2</pages> 
        <extension>3555</extension> 
        <recipient_name>Customer Service</recipient_name> 
        <channel>8</channel> 
        <delivered_to>
            <type>Share</type> 
            <destination>//fileserver/share/fax_inbound_20170313_133831_recv0943.pdf</destination> 
        </delivered_to>
        <delivered_to>
            <type>Print</type> 
            <destination>LOCAL DESTINATION</destination> 
        </delivered_to>
        <location /> 
        <caller_name>NAME OF THE CALLER</caller_name> 
        <caller_number>5551239999</caller_number> 
    </inbound_fax_entry>
    <inbound_fax_entry>
    ...
    </inbound_fax_entry>
</response>
```

The code mentioned above produces the following output in the debugTextBox1 control:

```
Key=response,value=
  Success

  fax_inbound_20170313_133831_recv0943.pdf
  complete
  2017-03-15T13:31:06
  5551239999
  12
  3555
  Customer Service
  ...
```

I can see that the it's just identifying the first key `response` and then stripping all of the other keys and displaying the values.  Honestly, I don't need the key names, my ultimate goal is to do some lite analysis (count how many faxes we've received, identify errors, etc) and then convert the data to CSV that can be exported.  If I could just get it to enumerate everything between each `inbound_fax_entry` keypair I could easily chop up the data like I want.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edit**  I was thinking about it and I do need the key names as well their corresponding values; not every fax has every XML element populated so I need to look for the `inbound_fax_entry` to delineate a new line in my csv and then record the values for each element, even if there's no data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your debugTextBox1 line needs to read el.Key, rather than el.Name.

Otherwise, you could try:

```
foreach (var el in xdoc.Elements())
        {
           debugTextBox1.Text = string.Format("Key={0},value={1}", el.Attributes["key"].Value.ToString(), el.Attributes["value"].Value.ToString());
        }
```

This question is similar to [How to read key/value in xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872575/how-to-read-key-value-in-xml-file) and the answers there may be helpful.